# What is the best django app that can allow users to log in using their twitter account?

Tags: python, django, twitter

I'd like to allow users to login into my Django site via their Twitter account.  What are my options?

Comment: I read your question as "I want to force Twitter users to login to my site."  Is that what you meant?

Comment: no,not force , just want to user login my site use their twitter account

Answer (score 1):

Django-SocialAuth can help you.
Here are link with example project and docs. 
http://uswaretech.com/blog/2009/08/django-socialauth-login-via-twitter-facebook-openid-yahoo-google/

Comment: i use it three days , but i cant running it successfuly.